# How to rotate log automaticly in mongo db?

Tags: windows, mongodb, logging

I want to automaticly rotate logs daily in mongo db for Windows OS. is it possible? Do you have a suggestion like powershell or anything else?

thanks

Comment: Log rotate will be used, when server is running as service. Are you running mongodb as service in windows?

Comment: yeah. mongodb is running as service in windows

Comment: then you need to set { logRotate: 1 } in admin database. Make sure you started service with logpath

Comment: Check the code added below

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

Make sure while starting service you specified **--logpath**

Comment: I can rotate my logs but i want to do tihs automaticly every day. I will use windows Task Scheduler. ok?

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this is an old question, but the OP asked for a way to do it automatically.

Windows Task Scheduler could be setup to run the following batch file at the desired time/frequency:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MONGO_BIN_DIR=C:\MongoDB\3.6\bin
PUSHD %MONGO_BIN_DIR%
ECHO db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ); > rotateLog.js
mongo admin rotateLog.js
@ECHO ON
```

Be sure to update the MONGO_BIN_DIR variable to match where your MongoDB is installed.  The script will switch to the bin directory, create a new rotateLog.js file to hold the command to rotate the log file (because the mongo client can only execute commands via *.js file and not directly).  It then will execute that javascript file.

If you want, you can always add a command before `@ECHO ON`, to delete that "temporary" rotateLog.js file.

As mentioned by jerry, you must have used the --logpath argument when starting the service or you must have the appropriate log section set in your config file.

**Alternatives:**

If you already have another application running that interact with the database, you could also add functionality there.  Most drivers for MongoDB include the ability to run a command against a database.  Find the correct syntax for your language driver to get reference to the "admin" database, then run the same `{ logRotate : 1 }` command against it.

Comment: You don't have to create a `.js` file. Run directly `mongo --eval "db.runCommand({logRotate:1})"`