# How to setup MongoDB log rotation on Windows?

Tags: mongodb, logrotate

I have a conf file for **mongod** where I am trying to set log rotation, the log file size, and the number of old instances to be kept.

I have added `logRotate: rename` to the conf file as follows:

```
systemLog:
  timeStampFormat: ctime
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: rename
  path: C:\Program Files\ApplicationName\logs\db.log
```

But I cannot find any documentation or examples that show how to specify the max size of the log file before it rotates and how many old instances to keep.
Also I don't know how to test this.

Apperently you need setup some kind of external process to send SIGUSR1 signal from OS to trigger rotation.

Any ideas? Has anyone actually done this successfully?

Comment: Can you help instead of voting down the question?

Comment: It's not that simple, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079426/mongo-log-rotation-does-not-work-on-windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206847/how-do-i-configure-mongodb-to-remove-old-log-files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888470/how-to-rotate-log-automaticly-in-mongo-db/50860546#50860546 and maybe https://sourceforge.net/projects/logrotatewin/files/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing available in MongoDB itself. Either you write all logs into one file:

```
systemLog
  logAppend: true
```

or you create a new log file every time you start MonogDB server:

```
systemLog
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: rename
```

In either case you have to delete/compress old log files manually with a 3rd party tool or by script.

In Linux you can trigger a log rotate by `kill -USR1` but I am not aware this would be available in Windows. You need to initiate log rotate from Mongo shell:

```
use admin
db.runCommand({ logRotate: 1 })
```

or

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand({ logRotate: 1 })
db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })
```

You can run it from command line with

```
mongo --eval "db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })"
```

Setup such task with Windows Task Scheduler. You may have a look at [LogRotateWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/logrotatewin/files/) which is an implementation of [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) utility for Windows Platform. I never tried it, but it seems to work as supposed to be. For sample logrotate configuration see [How can I disable the logging of MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887553/how-can-i-disable-the-logging-of-mongodb/66888748#66888748)

Note, for Linux in order not to lose any logs, you first have to rename the logfile and afterwards initiate the log rotate command. I don't know whether Windows behaves in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Wernfried-Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) answer, a lot of research, weeks of trial and error and frustration I figured out a working solution on windows.

---

###### Prerequisites

- You have a MongoDB-Service running with a configuration file `mongod.cfg`
- [LogRotateWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/logrotatewin/files/) is installed. This is a third party package to rotate the logfiles, based on the unix implementation. It provides many customizable functionalities like compression, when rotating is applied, old file deletion and more. You can find a full option list here [LogRotateWin Configuration](https://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/wiki/LogRotate/).
- Basic knowledge of Windows Taskscheduler.
- Very basic knowledge of bat files.

###### 1. Adjust the configuration file of the MongoDB-Service

1. Stop the service
2. Open the `mongod.cfg` and find the code lines where the `systemLog` is configured:

```
# where to write logging data. 
systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path:  E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log
      logRotate: reopen
```

Be sure, that you overwrite the path to your `mongod.log`. Be also sure, that `logAppend: true` and `logRotate: reopen` are set.

3. Delete the current `mongod.log` file
4. Restart the service

###### 2. Configure the logrotate configuration

This is my configuration. You can customize that to your own needs. But dont use `copy`, `copytruncate` and `create` and **dont** remove the `postrotate` commands!

```
E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log {
  nocompress
  daily
  size 100m
  missingok
  rotate 50
  postrotate
    E:\logrotate\notify_mongodb_service.bat
  endscript
}
```

This configuration rotates the logs uncompressed every day or if the size exceeded 100 megabyte. Maximum of 50 logs are stored, older files will be deleted. The postrotate script will be executed when the rotation succeeded.

###### 3. Create the `notify_mongodb_service.bat` file

This file sends a command to the MongoDB-Service, that a new file will be used. If you enabled authorization you can add `-u username -p password` aswell.

```
E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongo.exe --eval "db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })"
```

- Change the path to `mongo.exe` to the location on your system.
- Save the file and  be sure that the path in the `logrotate` configuration is the same! (the line between `postrotate` and `endscript`

**The command is stored in an extra file, because the LogRotateWin interprets the Brackets (`{}`) of the mongo command and throws an Exception.**

###### 4. Check that all is working

1. Open the folder of the logs. You should see a single file `mongod.log`.
2. Open a terminal and check that logrotation is working ( `-f` forces the logrotation even if no trigger was triggered):

```
logrotate logrotate.conf -f
```

A new log file should occur. (for me it is `mongod.log.1`)
The `mongod.log` should be empty.

3. Trigger something that will be logged. For example connect with monogdbCompass to your MongoDB.
4. Check `mongod.log`. The connection should be logged there.

###### 5. Create a Taskscheduler Job to run logrotation periodically

I wont talk about taskscheduler creation but here is an example of my configuration. You can import that file and modify it to your needs.

Also change the path of the `logrotate.exe` to your location of your system.

This job runs every hour to check if one or multiple triggers of logrotate triggered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2021-12-02T17:57:55.9541897</Date>
    <Author>Grayknife</Author>
    <Description>Execute Logrotate Hourly</Description>
    <URI>\docker\LogRotate</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2021-12-02T18:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>1234</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>E:\logrotate\logrotate.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>logrotate.conf</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>E:\logrotate</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

---

I hope i could help someone with that guide.

---

##### Edit 2022-05-01

I faced the issue that `logrotate` throws exception when there are more than 9 files:

```
E:\logrotate>E:\logrotate\logrotate.exe logrotate.conf -f
logrotate: Force option set to true
logrotate: Exception: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

logrotate: StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
   at logrotate.Program.AgeOutRotatedFiles(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi, String rotate_path)
   at logrotate.Program.RotateFile(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi)
   at logrotate.Program.Main(String[] args)

E:\logrotate>E:\logrotate\logrotate.exe logrotate.conf -f
logrotate: Force option set to true
logrotate: Exception: Access to the path 'E:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log.10' is denied.
logrotate: StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at logrotate.Program.DeleteRotateFile(String m_filepath, logrotateconf lrc)
   at logrotate.Program.AgeOutRotatedFiles(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi, String rotate_path)
   at logrotate.Program.RotateFile(logrotateconf lrc, FileInfo fi)
   at logrotate.Program.Main(String[] args)
E:\logrotate>
```

Quickfix for now is to set a maximum of 9 files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a python file logrotate.py with content:

```py
import os

# path to your mongod.log file
path = 'D:/MongoDB/Server/5.0/log/'

# you can insert a condition here that checks the size of mongod.log first
# ...

# send logrotate command through terminal
# if you don't have mongosh(ell) installed, replace by mongo / mongod
os.system('cmd /c "mongosh --eval "db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })"')

# delete rotated log file
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith('mongod.log.'):
        os.remove(path+file)

quit()
```

2. Create a batch file logrotate.bat with content:

```py
python logrotate.py
```

3. Create a task in Windows task scheduler that runs this program every X hours.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do it is just create a batch file to run the logRotate command and schedule it on Windows Task Scheduler.

1. the mongod(s) config file should have the logRorate = rename.

> ```
> systemLog:
>   destination: file
>   logAppend: false
>   path:  C:\<where you put the log>\mongod.log
>   logRotate: rename
> ```

2. create a batch file in a proper folder as:

> ```
> @Echo off
> C:\Program Files\mongosh\mongosh.exe -u <user name> -p <pw> --authenticationDatabase <auth db name> --eval "db.adminCommand( { logRotate: 1 } );"     
> @Echo "Clean up older than 30 days log file"
> Forfiles /P C:\<where you put the log>\ /m Mongo*.log.* /D -30 /C "cmd /c del /S /Q @file"
> ```

3. create a Windows scheduled task to run the above batch file.

This way no need to install something, simple, and easy to control the Mongodb logroate.